# Is there a way to create custom SPBasePermissions for my custom controls

Tags: 2010, permissions

I have actions and views of data in my custom controls an web parts. I would like to control access to them using the built-in SharePoint user/role-based permissions. Is there a way to define custom permissions that are configured and behave similar to SPBasePermissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research on this and I found out that it really wasn't designed to be extensible which is a shame. You have to roll your own permission system on top of the built-in SharePoint permissions and build your own administrative interface. I found a few blog posts that describe some hacks that can sort of use the built in SharePoint bit fields and add some new ones but those methods did not work for what I am interested in doing.